# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'readFile')

Tags: reactjs, electron, typeerror, node.js-fs, ipcrenderer

I am learning how to create an Electron react app and i want to use `fs.readFileSync()` in a renderer file (i'm trying to get it to work with the amazon rekognition api). I used contextBridge and ipcRenderer to expose the function. However, i keep getting the `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined` error when i click the button that tries to trigger `window.myFS.readFile()`.

If anyone is able to help, I would really appreciate if you could let me know what I'm doing wrong! Thank you so much!

The code I used are below:

main.js

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require('electron');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

function createMainWindow() {
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        title: 'Electron React App',
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000');

    return mainWindow
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    ipcMain.handle("readFile", (filePath)=>{return fs.readFileSync(filePath)})
    createMainWindow()
});

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
      app.quit()
    }
})
```

preload.js

```
const {contextBridge, ipcRenderer} = require("electron");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    "myFS", {
        readFile:(filePath) => {
            ipcRenderer.invoke("readFile", filePath);
        }
    }
);
```

Work.js

```
import React from "react";
const Rekognition = require("aws-sdk");

export default function Work() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button id="apibutton" onClick={credentials}>
                Try Amazon Rekognition!
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}

function credentials() {
    const rekognition = new Rekognition.Rekognition({
        region: 'ap-southeast-1'
    });
    rekognition.detectFaces({
        Attributes: ["ALL"],
        Image: {
            Bytes: window.myFS.readFile("./download.jpg")
        }
    }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err,err.stack);
        } else {
            console.log(data.json());
        }
    })

}
```

Error

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'readFile')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'readFile')
    at credentials (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:481:26)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38425:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38469:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38526:35)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38540:29)
    at executeDispatch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42683:7)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42709:11)
    at processDispatchQueue (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42720:9)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42729:7)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42889:16
```

**Update**
I realise the error only appears when I am running the app on local browser. It works fine when I run it on electron desktop app.

Comment: Can you please share the exact error, with file name, lines and stack?

Comment: Hi! i updated the with the actual error already, thanks!

Comment: I can't see anything wrong in the code you shared, is it your actual code? Do you get another error?

Comment: Yup, this is my actual code. There is no other error..

Comment: Humm, okay, are you sure you're supposed to pass the function like this to `Bytes`? Shouldn't it be `Bytes: () => window.myFS.readFile("./download.jpg")`?

Comment: Oh, you are right! Thank you! Do you mind explaining what is the significance of using `() =>` ?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure I can explain it correctly, but I assume that with how you wrote it, the function is immediatly called, so the value of `Bytes` is the result of `window.myFS.readFile("./download.jpg")` , which somehow throws an error. With the `() =>`, `Bytes` value is a function (that will call `readFile` when  executed).

Comment: Oh, actually after trying around some more, I found out the problem is likely because I was using the browser instead of the electron app!